# maven Failed to transfer jar file to nexus repository

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, nexus3

I have a nexus installed on my server behind a Nginx reverse proxy. I created `maven-snapshots` and `maven-releases` repositories. Redeployment is allowed for both repositories. Version policies are `Snapshot` for `maven-snapshots` and `Release` for `maven-releases`
I also created a Role with `nx-repository-view-*-*-*` privilege and a user `nx-dev` with that given role.
In my maven settings:

```
<server>
  <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
  <username>nx-dev</username>
  <password>NX-DEV-PASSWORD</password>
</server>

<server>
  <id>nexus-releases</id>
  <username>nx-dev</username>
  <password>NX-DEV-PASSWORD</password>
</server>
```

In my projects POM file:

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
        <url>https://nexus.mysite.com/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-releases</id>
        <url>https://nexus.mysite.com/repository/maven-releases/</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
```

When I run `mvn -X deploy` command, I get this error:

```
Failed to transfer file https://nexus.mysite.com/repository/maven-releases/com/myapp/my-app/0.0.3/myapp-0.0.3.jar  with status code 400
```

The `jar` file size is 47MB that is much less than 1G allowed in Nginx:

```
client_max_body_size 1G;
```

When I browse my repositories, I can see `.pom`, `.pom.md5` and `.pom.sha1` files but there is no `jar` file uploaded. Any idea?

EDIT:

In nexus log I see this warning:

```
2020-11-16 10:00:59,843+0000 WARN  [qtp1621258076-423]  
nx-payware org.sonatype.nexus.repository.view.handlers.ExceptionHandler - Invalid content: 
PUT /com/myapp/my-app/0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/my-app-0.0.3-20201116.095741-1.jar: 
org.sonatype.nexus.repository.InvalidContentException: 
Detected content type [application/x-sh], but expected [application/java-archive]: 
/com/myapp/my-app/0.0.3-SNAPSHOT/my-app-0.0.3-20201116.095741-1.jar
```

Comment: Code 400 means in Nexus that the artifacts already have been uploaded before ... Releases are immutable... so you have to make a new version. Furthermore the thing you given `/com/myapp/0.0.3/myapp-0.0.1.jar...` looks wrong...

Comment: Redeployment is allowed for both repositories and if I remove all artifacts from repositories and start again, I get the same results. All related files uploaded but no jar file.

Comment: Can you please show your pom file ...Do you have an nginx in front of nexus? If so why ? have you tried to remove nginx and directly accessing Nexus? Have you checked the logs of Nexus and the logs of nginx?

Comment: Nginx log was OK but in nexus log, I got a warning. I updated the question.

Comment: First this is a SNAPSHOT and not a release anymore ... have you checked the jar file? Can you do `unzip -t JARFILE`? And please add your pom file...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring boot executable jar files are being detected as a shell script. Disable file content validation in the hosted repository in order to work around it.

Uncheck Strict Content Type Validation:

[image]